# Prolog - Give out every nth element of a list

Tags: list, prolog

I'm working on a Prolog program which should load every *n*<sup>th</sup> element of a list into another list. For example:

```
?- pred([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j],3,R) => 
R = [c,f,i]
```

Where `pred` is the predicate I'm attempting to implement.

But I honestly don't know how to do it. I know that I need a counter, which represents the current position of my Head, so it's gonna be a /4 predicate summarized into a /3 one later one, like 
nth(list,number,result) :- nth(list,number,result,counter) or similiar.

Though, I don't know how to give the head a position number that can reset itself. Because once it hits *n* (let's say `n=3`, which is the `c` in the list), it has to turn back to 1 logically and count again up to 3, give out the element, and so on.

How can I work around these specific problems in my implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of how this could be implemented:

```
nth_pos(L, N, R):-
    nth_pos(L, 1, N, [], R).

nth_pos([], I, N, Acc, Acc).

nth_pos([H|T], I, N, Acc, R):-
    I =:= N,
    append(Acc, [H], Acc2),
    I2 is 1,   
    nth_pos(T, I2, N, Acc2, R).

nth_pos([H|T], I, N, Acc, R):-
    I < N,
    I2 is I + 1,   
    nth_pos(T, I2, N, Acc, R).
```

**Test-run:**

```
?- nth_pos([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j],3,R).
R = [c, f, i] .

?- nth_pos([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j],1,R).
R = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i|...]
```

> But I honestly don't know how to do it. I know that I need a counter,
>   which represents the current position of my Head, so it's gonna be a
>   /4 predicate summarized into a /3 one later one, like
>   nth(list,number,result) :- nth(list,number,result,counter) or
>   similiar.

Yes you are on the right track, note that an accumulator is used as well to build up the list so we get `pred/5`. Hope it helps. Note that this is not the only way to solve it.